# Fluid background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to use a fluid background image using 'img' for a header, whilst keeping the menu and page contents directly beneath it inline with the fluid resizing.

The CSS is:

```
img#header-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
        z-index:10;
}

#content-wrapper {padding-top:266px;float:left;overflow: hidden;border-bottom: 0;position: relative;background-color:white;height: 100%;}
```

The html:

```
<div id="header-wrapper" class="clearfix">
<img id="header-wrapper" src="/images/new-header.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use some javascript to get the required height?

Comment: Just float #header-wrapper and #content-wrapper left and remove all that absolute/relative positioning stuff and it works

Comment: First issue I see is you're using the same id for the div and the img. ID's are supposed to be unique items. Meaning one per page.

Comment: @twodayslate - They don't need Javascript.

Comment: I thought he wanted a background image. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made this loads more complicated than it needs to be with absolute positioning. All you need is `height: auto` on the image.

**[LIVE DEMO >](http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/cDvYQ/)**

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="http://www.dev.inside-guides.co.uk/images/new-header.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="nav">
    NAV
</div>​

.header {
    width: 100%;
    margin 0 0 10px 0;
}

.header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.nav {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You 100% DO NOT need JavaScript for this.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. There's nothing wrong with this approach at all.

Comment: Thought so. That was what I was going to suggest.